# Telegram. WebApp. Проверка подлинности пользователя. Не сходится хэш

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть телеграмм-бот с веб-хуком кинутым на веб-сервер джанго. Есть веб-приложение телеграмма, которое при инициации вызывает вьюху джанги и возвращает шаблон.
В этом шаблоне, согласно [документации телеграма](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#initializing-mini-apps), в head вписан скрипт

```
<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
```

И далее в body мне нужно проверить подлинность пользователя телеграмма. Я следовал [документации о проверке данных](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#validating-data-received-via-the-mini-app) и советам из инета и в шаблоне прописал следующий скрипт:

```
<script>
        const WebApp = window.Telegram.WebApp;
        let initDataURLSP = new URLSearchParams(WebApp.initData);
        var hash = initDataURLSP.get('hash');

        initDataURLSP.delete('hash');
        initDataURLSP.sort();
        var checkDataString = initDataURLSP.toString().replaceAll('&', '\n');

        let data_send = {
            'hash': hash,
            'checkDataString': checkDataString,
        };
        fetch(
                'https://address/backend/check_hash/',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data_send),
                }
        );
</script>
```

На бэке это принимается вьюхой:

```
    @csrf_exempt
    def check_hash(request: HttpRequest):
        request_dict = json.loads(request.body)
        data_check_string = request_dict['checkDataString']
        tg_hash = request_dict['hash']
    
        import hashlib, hmac, os
        from dotenv import load_dotenv
    
        load_dotenv()
    
        token = os.getenv('TOKEN_DJEM_DEV_BOT')
    
        secret_key = hmac.new(
            key="WebAppData".encode(),
            msg=token.encode(),
            digestmod=hashlib.sha256
        ).digest()
        local_hash = hmac.new(
            key=secret_key,
            msg=data_check_string.encode(),
            digestmod=hashlib.sha256
        ).hexdigest()
        check = tg_hash == local_hash
        ... # Дальше идёт возврат хттп-ответа.
```

Так вот, check  у меня приходит False и tg_hash != local_hash

Пробовал присылать неизменённую initData на бэк:

```
const WebApp = window.Telegram.WebApp;
let data_send = {
    'checkDataString': WebApp.initData,
};
fetch(
        'https://address/backend/poll_data/',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data_send),
        }
);
```

и уже там ещё форматировать:

```
    data_check_string = request_dict['checkDataString']
    data_check_string_list: list = data_check_string.split('&')
    tg_hash = data_check_string_list.pop(-1)[5:]
    data_check_string_list.sort()
    data_check_string = '\n'.join(data_check_string_list)
```

Результат неотличим.

Как пройти проверку пользователя средствами python и js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение на [просторах Интернета.](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/3b66a2b2e0a90ffc80582be3d1ef0e7045ce51fa/aiogram/utils/web_app.py#L8) Там код на пайтоне из библиотеки aiogram. Среди прочего есть функция, которая принимает токен бота и init_data (которую присылает веб-приложение с фронта) и возвращает булево значение, соответствующее подлинности пользователя:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
from operator import itemgetter
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl


def check_webapp_signature(token: str, init_data: str) -> bool:
    """
    Check incoming WebApp init data signature

    Source: https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#validating-data-received-via-the-web-app

    :param token:
    :param init_data:
    :return:
    """
    try:
        parsed_data = dict(parse_qsl(init_data))
    except ValueError:
        # Init data is not a valid query string
        return False
    if "hash" not in parsed_data:
        # Hash is not present in init data
        return False

    hash_ = parsed_data.pop('hash')
    data_check_string = "\n".join(
        f"{k}={v}" for k, v in sorted(parsed_data.items(), key=itemgetter(0))
    )
    secret_key = hmac.new(
        key=b"WebAppData", msg=token.encode(), digestmod=hashlib.sha256
    )
    calculated_hash = hmac.new(
        key=secret_key.digest(), msg=data_check_string.encode(), digestmod=hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest()
    return calculated_hash == hash_
```

Пока не разобрался почему мой код не работал, а этот работает, но вопрос решён.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)